# the miracle of 'this' keyword JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this

```
var obj = {};
obj.fn = function() {
    return this;
    }
```

output: **Window object** 
is the 'this' not pertaning to 'obj' which is the objectof property 'fn'?

but if I make declare like this below...

```
var obj = { 
    fn: function() { 
        console.log(this);
       }
    }
```

output is... **Object object** 
are they not the same?

Comment: How are you executing your first example? Are you doing `obj.fn()` or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your examples shall return the object itself with the console log of `this`, the window object is logged when reading `this` in the global scope:

```
    var obj = {};
    obj.fn = function() {
      console.log(this);
    }

    // logs window
    console.log(this);

    // logs object
    obj.fn();

    var obj1 = { 
      fn: function() { 
        console.log(this);
      }
    }

    // logs object
    obj1.fn();
```

`this` will always take the value of the containing scope